How to force Blazor page to execute script on navigation
What causes a script tag to be executed in a Blazor Web App?
It appears that when a page in my test app is navigated to with the the URL or refreshed using the browser my "test.js" script runs which adds a "style" element to "head" which changes the background to green. However, if I click on the "Home" link (or "Counter", or "Weather") from the left navigation pane, the "style" tag is removed from "head", which means the "test.js" script did not run.
How do I force the script to re-run each time the page is navigated to using the links on the left?
On app load (or refresh, or nav using a URL):

After navigating to the link "Home" using the left pane navigation:

Code:


You need to show some code.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis code added.

Hi.   Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.

There are 2 solutions for this.
Solution1: Use Interactivemode in App.razor
...
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
...
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
...

Solution2: If you only want to use SSR. You could use "PageScript" which allows you to excute javascript without refresh(force reload).

Install package BlazorPageScript.
Create a file name App.razor.js with following code


export function onUpdate() {
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<style>body{background:green;}</style>");
}


In App.razor use the file like following:

...
    <Routes  />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <BlazorPageScript.PageScript Src="./Components/App.razor.js"> </BlazorPageScript.PageScript>
...

Then the navigation will also trigger the "onUpdate" event to execute the js code.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/static-server-rendering?view=aspnetcore-8.0
